# Tuple notation for non-negative integers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have three variables $x_1, x_2, x_3$ that can only be non-negative integers, i.e., $x_1 \in \mathbb{N}_0$, $x_2 \in \mathbb{N}_0$, and $x_3 \in \mathbb{N}_0$. Is it correct to write this in a tuple like $(x_1,x_2,x_3) \in \mathbb{N}_0^3$? If not, what is the correct way?

Comment: that is correct

Comment: Yes, or $(\Bbb N_0)^3$ for more clarity.

Comment: Another option for writing it is to enclose the $\mathbb{N}_0$ in braces, giving you ${\mathbb{N}_0}^3$. I'm not sure I actually like that, though.

Comment: @TannerSwett - Oh, you mean add braces _in the underlying LaTeX_, so that the superscript isn't directly over the subscript! I kept thinking "I don't see any braces" and wondering if my rendering was broken.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Yup, sorry for my ambiguous writing!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Unless you're actually considering them as a tuple elsewhere, you can also just write this as

$$x_1, x_2, x_3 \in \mathbb N_0$$

And I would argue that introducing the tuple and the product space solely for the purpose of specifying this constraint makes it more complicated for no reason.

So if you need the tuple, yes, use that notation. But if you don't need the tuple, use this one.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this is correct.  You could also write $$(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in\mathbb{N}_0 \times \mathbb{N}_0 \times \mathbb{N}_0.$$

An alternative that avoids duplication is
$$\text{$x_i\in \mathbb{N}_0$ for $i\in \{1,2,3\}$}.$$